# Reimplementing acceptNavigationRequest()

Tags: c++, qt

I am making simple web redoer with Qt 5.1 on Windows 8 .

For example, if I navigate to Google, login and then search "hello world", I want to save the infomations and redo later (i.e. redo submitting form and login).

What I tried is this.

. Create new Qt GUI application ;

. Add class :

```
Name: MyWebView , Base class: QWebView
Inherits QWidget
header: mywebview.h
src: mywebview.cpp
```

. Add class :

```
Name: MyWebPage, Base class: QWebPage
Inherits QObject
header: mywebpage.h
src: mywebpage.cpp
```

. Modify MyWebPage.h :

```
add
public:
bool QWebPage::acceptNavigationRequest(QWebFrame * frame, const QNetworkRequest & request, NavigationType type);
```

. Modify MyWebPage.cpp :

```
    add
    #include <QMessageBox>
    add
    bool MyWebPage::acceptNavigationRequest(QWebFrame *frame, const QNetworkRequest &request, NavigationType type)
{
     QMessageBox::about(0,"it works","it works");   
}
```

. Modify MyWebView.h :

```
add
#include "mywebpage.h"
add
public:
MyWebPage *mwp;
MyWebPage * page(){ return mwp;}
```

. Add the following code to untitled1.pro :

```
QT       += webkitwidgets
```

. Change main.cpp to :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "mywebview.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    MyWebView wv;
    wv.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

. Build and run.

I expect that every time I click buttons(form or link), the "it works" message is displayed by `QMessageBox::about`, but it never happened.

How can I reimplement `acceptNavigationRequest` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed mywebview.cpp to

```
#include "mywebview.h"
#include "mywebpage.h"
MyWebView::MyWebView(QWidget *parent) :
    QWebView(parent), mwp(new MyWebPage(this))
{
    setPage(mwp);
}
```

and it works fine